# How can I store github credentials only for one repository?

Tags: github

My question is about working with GitHub repositories as managment tools for customer specific code.

- I have around 100 customers
- I have a GitHub Repository for each customer with his data tranformations (many t-sql scripts)
- All Repos are private
- I have a VPN Connection to each customers server to work there
- I use GitHub desktop to access GitHub

When I work for a customer I checkout his repository on his server, work on then transformations and commit all changes. It works very well, I have all customer code avaiable on my computer and on the customer side, without copy and paste etc.

The only problem i face, is the problems of storing credentials on customers server side. I would like to have the credentials stored to checkout / commit this repository, but not to checkout other repositories, this should result in a new request for credentials.

Of course I could skip saving credentials, but with 10-20 commits per day, motivation for this is not so big.

Are there any GitHub Clients / Commandline tools / best practice rules to do this ?

Comment: Add the users to your Organization and have them update themselves with their credentials. You could also use SSH or deploy keys but not sure of that breaks their license agreement.

Comment: I'm the only user. The problem is only about storing my own credentials.

Comment: Deploy Keys seam to be a solution for my problem - thank you. According to the github guide "A deploy key is an SSH key that is stored on your server and grants access to a single GitHub repository. This key is attached directly to the repository instead of to a personal user account."